# inserting kernel module after make mrproper

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I download the kernel source, compile it and run the new kernel. I am making some change to kvm kernel module and testing it.

So this is what I do after making some change in the kernel source.

```
make M=arch/x86/kvm
```

After this I am able to successfully insert the kernel module.

By mistake I did `make mrproper` which cleans all the binaries and byproducts on a linux compile.

So, is there a way now to make my kernel module only and insert it into current booted kernel or should I compile the whole kernel again and replace the new vmlinuz with vmlinuz file in /boot.

I can do the second option but it takes time and is not the most intelligent way for this small problem.

Comment: It's been a while, so I may not remember correctly (or things may have changed), but did you try `make modules`?

Comment: Running `make mrproper` removes the kernel configuration, you should try to restore it before trying `make M=... modules`.

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel is currently running you can try running `make cloneconfig`. This should configure the kernel tree exactly like the running kernel.

The compiled module should then match your kernel.

Comment: I am using the kernel source 3.0.27 and`make cloneconfig` returns an error with no rule to make target cloneconfig